# How to extract attribute ID from XML file with Groovy

Tags: groovy

Here is the XML file:

```
<beans>
    <jee:jndilookup jndi-name="" id="tenantDataSourceJndi" />
</beans>
```

Comment: show your coding attempt

Comment: this xml can't be parsed because `jee:` prefix not declared

Comment: def bookAuthorId1 = beans.jee.@id                                                     println bookAuthorId1

Comment: how can I solve it?I mean '':''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you get it:

```
def xml = """<beans xmlns:jee="http://example">
    <jee:jndilookup jndi-name="" id="tenantDataSourceJndi" />
</beans>"""
pXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
println pXml.'**'.find{it.name() == 'jndilookup'}.@id
```

Check it quickly online [Demo](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5202988410863616)

**EDIT:** based on OP comment
If you need to read xml from file, then use below:

```
pXml = new XmlSlurper().parse('C:/Users/jndi.xml')
println pXml.'**'.find{it.name() == 'jndilookup'}.@id
```

Comment: Thankks Rao.It is working.But my xml file and groovy  are not in the same file.

Comment: I am trying something like def xml = '''"C:/Users/jndi.xml'''' but it isnt working

Comment: @Khagan, please check the EDIT part

Comment: Glad to know that. Appreciate if you can [accept it as answered](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Khagan, are you looking for something more? It does not even a min to accept I believe.

Comment: I want to accept,but it isnt working,may be I am doing something wrong.Can you explain me how can I do it?